# Bootstrap 3 merge rows and columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can't figure out what is the problem with my code. I'm very new in bootstrap my problem is kinda trivial. One of my field is out of position. I have tried a different route by making only one row and instead of increasing the div sizes I reduced them, but it had the exact same problem. (Run the code in full screen mode).

Please if you can help me out!

```css
.row {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.col-sm-3, .col-sm-6 {
    border:solid 2px black;
}

div {
    height:200px;
}
.two-div {
    height:400px;
}
.three-div {
    height:600px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 three-div pull-left">Works</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">Works</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 two-div pull-right">Works</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 two-div">Works</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 three-div">Works</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 two-div pull-right">Works</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">:(</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What **exactly** are you trying to do? Just make the white section full width? Simply use `col-sm-12`. If the problem is with the overlap, it's because you're defining fixed heights in your classes.

Comment: I'm kind of impressed you managed to do that. I don't think it's going to work out the way you expect it though. It's really only working as well as it is because you defined `height: 200px` for **all divs**, including the parent `.row` elements that have children taller than 200px. I can't think of a way to make this work without more hacks, but you can use `translateY()` to put that div up in the spot you want it http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qrLbOZ

Comment: "masonry" or "isotope" (with the masonry layout mode) are a couple of js plugins that make layouts like this easier, and have neat effects http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some nesting and `pull-right` on the appropriate columns you can reverse the `float:left` and make it work (albeit a hack!)...

http://www.codeply.com/go/rgHEL6DW12

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 three-div">works</div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">works</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 three-div pull-right">works</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 two-div pull-right">works</div>
                <div class="col-sm-8 pull-right">
                    ;-)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 two-div">works</div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 two-div">works</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Think about it like this...

[image]

http://www.codeply.com/go/rgHEL6DW12

Answer (score 0):

Your unhappy smiley box is off because your setting different heights for the containers. I altered your code to explain how you work with BS grid system. See comments.

```css
.row {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.col-sm-3,.col-sm-6 {
    border:solid 2px black;
}
div { height:200px; }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 three-div">Works</div> <!-- no need for pulling left. BS does that already -->
            <div class="col-sm-6">Works</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 two-div">Works</div> <!-- no need for pulling right -->
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 two-div">Works</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 three-div">Works</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-9">Works</div> <!-- use -offset-X to move your divs horizontally along the grid -->
        </div>
        <div class="row">    
           <div class="col-sm-6">:(</div>        
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ironic that your name is "Yolo" and the questioners name is "YoloAcc"??